# How to set up an EC2 (14.04 "Trusty") instance which will be compatible with PHP SDK 1.6.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

This is a tricky one as outlined below, however if there is a genius out
there that could make a suggestion with/out reading the synopsis I would 
be eternally grateful.

- How to set up an EC2 (14.04 "Trusty") instance which will be compatible with PHP SDK 1.6.2?
- How to downgrade PHP on existing instance (14.04 "Trusty") from 5.5.9 to 5.3.10?

**Synopsis:**

I have an application set up on three instances. 2 of which are
on my own Amazon EC2 instances, the other one on Amazon EC2 instance at work.

On the instance in work we have PHP5.3.10 which allows me to create,read
update & delete using the PHP SDK as normal. However both instances on my own
account (running PHP5.5.10) are preventing me from doing so and are reporting a 
"500 internal error" when checked on the browser console. This may be caused by 
the version of PHP on my instances however no online documentation suggest this 
to be the case.

I have already changed the repo on one instance to 'Raring' however this was a disaster...

Comment: The internal error should be logged somewhere, likely in Apache or PHP logs. Can you dig for that and add it to the question?

Comment: Hi Halfer, yeah the log I have is showing 'segmentation fault (core dumped)'. regarding /etc/php.